# How does the operating system set up memory boundaries?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, memory-access

Is there a hardware interrupt that is pre-configured by the OS or something?  Try to keep the answer on the scale of a register or so.

Are some special preparatory signals sent across the bridges to the hardware to make boundaries?

Comment: What research have you done? Have you read the Wikipedia articles on those topics, e.g.,  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory?  Have you consulted a textbook on operating systems? We want you to do research/self-study before asking. This helps you ask a better question, helps us give you better answers, and helps others who may come across your question. See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How memory boundaries work depends on the system, but the most common method is a [memory management unit (MMU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) or a memory protection unit (MPU). Whenever the CPU makes a memory access, the address is analyzed by the MPU or MMU. An MPU either allows or forbid the access; an MMU is more powerful and translates the virtual address passed by the processor into a physical address used by the memory controller.

When the access is denied, this triggers a kind of interrupt (not necessarily an actual interrupt because it often comes from inside the CPU; the vocabulary depends on the architecture but it's often called *trap* or *exception*). Other than that, no interrupts are involved.

On most architectures, the MMU is part of the CPU. So MMU configuration does not involve any “signals sent across the bridges” (did you mean the *buses*?).

The MPU/MMU acts based on tables. The CPU sets the tables, generally by setting a register which contains a pointer to the main table. The operating system normally modifies the table whenever a context switch between tasks occurs or a task allocates or frees memory.

Comment: This is exactly the answer that I was looking for.  I wasn't sure if this was implemented in some conversation protocol between the components and the CPU, mostly.  It's interesting to know that this is a hardware component too.  BTW: I think that I did mean buses :D

Comment: I've found out my confusion: I'd thought that the MMU's bank switching was integrated into the north and south bridge chips, which is why I'd said that instead of buses.

Comment: I've read that the whenever the memory is out of bounds, the CPU sends a trap to the operating system. What does that actually mean? Since a trap is a software interrupt, I'm assuming that a certain code gets executed in the CPU but I'm unable to picture it correctly. Would love to get this clarified. Thanks.

Comment: @Jamāl The details vary depending on the processor, but the general principle is the same: it's like an interrupt, but one that is triggered by an event on the CPU itself rather than from a peripheral. The processor does something like: set the `fault_instruction_address` register to the address of the instruction that tried to access memory out of bounds, the `fault_data_address` register to the memory address that it tried to access, and the `fault_flags` register to some value indicating the nature of the problem; then jump to the address that the OS placed in the `fault_handler` register.

Comment: I get the idea now, thanks!